# Problem with adding parameter

Tags: c#, ado.net, parameters

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@name";
param.Value = tableName;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from @name", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The above code results in the following error message:

> Must declare the table variable "@name".

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong query

```
select * from @name
```

Please correct it, after `From` table or view name is expected to come, you should put your param like `'select * from MyTable where col1 = @param'`.

You can't put @param instead of table name. Use `String.Format("select * from {0}", "MyTable");` instead.

Comment: No, I don't need any condition. I just want get all columns from the given table.

Comment: You can't put @param instead of table name. Use String.Format("select * from {0}", "MyTable"); instead.

Answer (score 4):

Parameterized queries generally deal with parameters for *values* within the query - not for table names, column names etc. I don't believe SQL Server supports parameterizing the table name.

You probably want to restrict the names to a known set of valid table names (to avoid SQL injection attacks etc), and use normal string replacement / formatting / whatever to construct the query.

Comment: That is correct. You can't use a parameter as table name in SQL Server.

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from "+tableName, con);?
Or may be exists better method?

Comment: @Aram: Something like that, yes - or maybe use `string.Format`. You'll want to be *very* careful with dynamically generated SQL though.

Answer (score 1):

rather than passing name in the query you can easily replace it over here

```
string s = "select * from " + name;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

but this will cause the sql injection error

so i would like to suggest you go for dyanmic query execution in the sql server which you can do with **SP_ExecuteSQL**.

Comment: Thanks I  write how you say. I just want to  write it another way.

Comment: @Aram Gevorgyan - in this query name value can be altered to any thing which may be not acceptable by the sql server query ......... but go for the SQ_EXECUTESQL resolve your issue easily

Comment: @Pranay Rana  I don't think so, because these name come from winform in wihch I have tables and onclick them I show table content,so the name must be correct. But thanks for help. And can you tell me where can I read more about SQ_EXECUTESQL ?

Comment: @Aram Gevorgyan - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx link for sp_executesql